# Why d@d or something like that is valid? InternetAddress

Tags: java, validation, email

I have a standard method like:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
        emailAddr.validate();
    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why don't catch and exception with arrays like h@h, /////@h, ****@d??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are valid because you can have domains names without a dot. You can set them yourself via the `hosts` file. `localhost` being an example.

Without a scheme to further specify `@` can indicate either an email address or a URL with username (and optional password) before it.

email: `me@localhost` should be valid

url: `me:mypass@localhost` should also be valid

Answer (score 0):

See [RFC](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html)

> Positively speaking, this means that the valid constituents of an atom
>   are the following:
>
> !"#$%&'*+-/0123456789=? @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^_
>   `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~

Answer (score 0):

Email address format is quite flexible and complex at the same time, and it has always been a big mess to manage.

As specified in the documentation InternetAddress follows the specification of [RFC-822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt).
You can have a look and will understand what I meant :)

Comment: In concrete terms, all of your "invalid" test cases are actually syntactically valid as far as RFC5322 (née 822) is concerned.  That the domains you use for testing do not resolve is an application-level error, an in principle that could change (especially now that the ICANN is rolling out new top-level domains at a steady rate, although I believe they will not allow single-letter TLDs).